# My srt file includes positioning formatting, but I lose this when embeding into mp4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, srt

I am trying to embed an srt subtitle file with subtitle positioning into an mp4 file using ffmpeg.

Is this possible? Every time I try I lose the positioning formatting.

Answer (score 0):

From [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) that includes a table showing which containers support which subtitle formats, it is clear that mp4 does not support the more sophisticated formats that, for example, mk does. By using mkv I can preserve the positioning formatting in the srt file